# Sonar violation squid:S1612

Tags: java, lambda, sonarqube

```
public class FetchVarableList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "Abi", "Fin", 2000);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "Chandu", "OPs", 5000);
        Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "mahesh", "HR", 8000);
        Employee e4 = new Employee(4, "Suresh", "Main", 1000);

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
        empList.add(e1); empList.add(e2); empList.add(e3); empList.add(e4);

        List<String> emps = empList.stream().map(p -> p.getEmpName())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        emps.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This about programming is working fine, but in that I have a sonar violation,
how to change to lambda expression? I need some help

Comment: .map(Employee::getEmpName)

Comment: Thanks , it is working

Answer (score 4):

Though the implementation is correct, you might want to use a method reference instead :

```
List<String> emps = empList.stream().map(Employee::getEmpName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which is what the rule ***[squid:S1612](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.sonarsource.java/java-checks/3.4/org/sonar/l10n/java/rules/squid/S1612.html)*** expects.

> Method/constructor references are more compact and readable than using lambdas, and are therefore preferred.

Comment: but this is only applicable to static methods

Comment: @dragonalvaro No, it works for any method.